# Python function returns answer only under "print" feature

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to run the below code but it doesn't return anything unless I add "print". I saw a similar issue question here and tried to check if it's the same as described in the answers but unfortunately I couldn't fix it. Any help is appreciated.

```
def compute_reference_eig(Neigen, exact=True, ref_solver=None):
    if exact:
        eigenvalues = []
        for i in range(Neigen+1):
            if (i%2)==0:
                eig = (i**2)*math.pi**2
            else: 
                eig = ((i-1)**2)*math.pi**2
            eigenvalues.append(eig)
        return eigenvalues[1::] #return  print('Exact Eigenvalues:\n', eigenvalues[1::])                             
    else: # add for reference solver when exact is unavailable. Yet to implement.
        return None
    
compute_reference_eig(3, exact=True, ref_solver=None)
```

Comment: You can't see the result of a `return`. If you want to see the result you have to print it. A REPL will do that for you, but don't expect this behaviour if you run a script.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it returns the desired thing, but you are not storing the result in any variable. In the last line, you just call the function, which without any print statements won't print anything. You may want do change this line

```py
compute_reference_eig(3, exact=True, ref_solver=None)
```

to

```py
eigen_values = compute_reference_eig(3, exact=True, ref_solver=None)
print(eigen_values)
```